# What background do I need to know to understand the paper published by Alan Turing mentioning the halting problem?

Tags: computational-mathematics, decidability

I am interested in understanding the proof that mentioned that the halting problem is an undecidable problem from the original paper of Alan Turing's called "ON COMPUTABLE NUMBERS, WITH AN APPLICATION TO
THE ENTSCHEIDUNGSPROBLEM" .
I am not interested in the simplifications of the proof like the videos on YouTube explaining the idea in a more easy manner.. I want to read the original paper and understand the real proof as it was originally written with no pop mathematics involved.
Still I found it a bit hard and I didn't even know where was the beginning of the proof in the paper.
So I was wondering if someone could help me by telling me what background knowledge I need to be able to understand the proof easily .. what topics do I need to study and understand.
Thanks for everyone who would help!

Edit: if you don't recommend reading the original paper, then what do you recommend reading ?

Comment: "Original paper" and "popular exposition" are not the only options. There are also totally-rigorous *modern* presentations of the argument which greatly improve on the original in terms of clarity. I don't actually recommend Turing's original paper for your first read of the proof.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks for your comment ... So what do you recommend ?

Comment: Any of the standard introductory textbooks on computability theory or complexity theory will have proof. Sipser, Boolos/Burgess/Jeffrey, Soare, Cutland, Arora/Barak, and plenty of others.